element-wise add / subtract / multiply / divide operation in two lists in C#
Considering element-wise add / subtract / multiply / divide operation in two lists. I have the code as follows.
public class Calculate
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2)
    {
        return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => (dynamic)first + (dynamic)second).Cast<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Subtract<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2)
    {
        return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => (dynamic)first - (dynamic)second).Cast<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Multiply<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2)
    {
        return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => (dynamic)first * (dynamic)second).Cast<T>();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Divide<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2)
    {
        return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => (dynamic)first / (dynamic)second).Cast<T>();
    }

}

Tests
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    doubles.Add((double)i);
}
foreach (var element in Calculate.Add(doubles, doubles))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
}

It just works, but dealing with dynamic, I am wondering if it is the right way to do it? Is the code generic enough?

What is "better"? What don't you like about your current code?

Maybe generic math can improve your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math

You most likely want to use Generic Math to be able to do math on elements without "dynamic". Anytime you use "dynamic" you should consider if it is the right way to do it. If you are doing anything mathy you might want to consider some library, like math .net

As a rule-of-thumb, everytime I type "dynamic" I picture that "Are you sure about that?"-Meme in my head. "Is the code generic enough?" - not sure what you mean by that? But I am confident I know people that can make this implementation break. If you mean that?

Might be a better fit on code review since that seems to be what you're asking for.

I suggest using generic math here, e.g.
using System.Numerics;

...

public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) 
  where T : IAdditionOperators<T, T, T> {

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input1);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input2);

  return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => first + second);
}

We can implement all the rest operations in the similar way:
public static IEnumerable<T> Subtract<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) 
  where T : ISubtractionOperators<T, T, T> {

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input1);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input2);

  return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => first - second);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Multiply<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) 
  where T : IMultiplyOperators<T, T, T> {

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input1);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input2);

  return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => first * second);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Divide<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) 
  where T : IDivisionOperators<T, T, T> {

  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input1);
  ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(input2);

  return input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => first / second);
}


Generic Maths is the way to go, but if you don't have it then if you're happy to do some general set up code, then this would work with any type.
public static class Calculate
{
    public enum Operator { Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division, }
    
    public static void Register<T>(Operator @operator, Func<T, T, T> operation)
    {
        _operators[(typeof(T), @operator)] = operation;
    }
    
    private static Dictionary<(Type, Operator), Delegate> _operators = new Dictionary<(Type, Operator), Delegate>();
    
    private static IEnumerable<T> Operate<T>(this Func<T, T, T> operation, IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) =>
        input1.Zip(input2, (first, second) => operation(first, second));
    
    public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) =>
        ((Func<T, T, T>)_operators[(typeof(T), Operator.Addition)]).Operate(input1, input2);

    public static IEnumerable<T> Subtract<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) =>
        ((Func<T, T, T>)_operators[(typeof(T), Operator.Subtraction)]).Operate(input1, input2);

    public static IEnumerable<T> Multiply<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) =>
        ((Func<T, T, T>)_operators[(typeof(T), Operator.Multiplication)]).Operate(input1, input2);

    public static IEnumerable<T> Divide<T>(IEnumerable<T> input1, IEnumerable<T> input2) =>
        ((Func<T, T, T>)_operators[(typeof(T), Operator.Division)]).Operate(input1, input2);
}

Now, you have to do this set up at the beginning of your code:
Calculate.Register<double>(Calculate.Operator.Addition, (x, y) => x + y);
Calculate.Register<double>(Calculate.Operator.Subtraction, (x, y) => x - y);
Calculate.Register<double>(Calculate.Operator.Multiplication, (x, y) => x * y);
Calculate.Register<double>(Calculate.Operator.Division, (x, y) => x / y);

Now, your test code works as is:
List<double> doubles = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    doubles.Add((double)i);
}
foreach (var element in Calculate.Add(doubles, doubles))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
}

That produces:
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18


You could even use reflection to auto-register those Funcs using CreateDelegate<Func<T, T, T>>
